# Postfix send emails with few days delay

Tags: debian, postfix

Postfix is sending emails with few days delay. Don't know why since I have no delay sending setings in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. It is actually happening only for one domain. I have multiple domains on server and only one has this problem.

Comment: What are the postfix log messages associated with those messages? Does the output of `mailq` indicate any reason for the delay?

Comment: That are some weird messages, mostly spam. But I am afraid its happening to regular emails too. mailq is small, nothing weird, around 20emails at peak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by multiple IP addresses with gray-listing on the delivery server, which caused this problem.